# Web-Scraping Script too long?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've been working on a process to scrape the Game Result column from all of the links listed (each one is unique with random ID #'s).

This script is not running? It's fine with less links. I can't seem to get the result for the full list - my backup plan would be to just run it in bunches, but not really ideal?

I was thinking I could potentially pull out the ids in a list, and then loop through them (so it's only one URL), but I wasn't sure if this would make a difference? I also wasn't sure how to execute and didn't want to spend time figuring it out if not worth it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

profiles = []
urls = ['https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=2&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=6&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=7&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=17&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=23&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=27&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=28&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=30&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=37&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=43&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=47&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=51&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=52&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=14927&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=61&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=62&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=66&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=67&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=68&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=71&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=72&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=77&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=80&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=81&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=83&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=87&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=30135&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=90&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=94&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=96&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=97&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=99&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=101&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=102&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=115&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=116&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=127&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=129&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=48&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=136&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=147&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=148&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=149&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=153&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=1013&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=285&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=786&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=156&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=158&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=165&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=167&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=169&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=172&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=173&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=178&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=176&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=30095&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=189&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=191&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=193&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=194&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=196&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=198&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=201&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=202&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=204&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=207&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=1068&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=220&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=222&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=228&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=229&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=28755&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=231&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=234&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=236&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=244&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=1092&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=248&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=249&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=251&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=255&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=253&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=254&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=260&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=261&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=1104&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=270&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=275&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=19651&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=283&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=287&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=290&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=294&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=299&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=305&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=2699&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=306&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=310&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=311&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=314&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=315&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=316&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=317&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=327&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=1157&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=331&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=340&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=342&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=346&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=352&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=355&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=28600&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=361&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=363&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=365&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=366&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=370&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=371&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=369&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=381&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=386&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=387&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=388&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=402&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=406&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=410&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=414&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=416&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=419&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=430&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=432&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=669&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=439&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=440&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=444&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=446&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=450&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=454&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=471&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=472&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=482&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=483&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=485&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=488&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=489&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=490&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=493&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=500&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=501&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=503&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=505&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=508&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=509&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=514&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=518&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=519&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=521&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=523&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=527&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=528&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=539&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=541&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=550&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=553&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=1320&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=554&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=556&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=559&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=308&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=562&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=563&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=574&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=576&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=579&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=587&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=590&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=600&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=606&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=609&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=610&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=617&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=624&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=625&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=626&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=630&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=631&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=1356&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=635&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=639&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=647&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=649&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=654&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=655&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=659&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=660&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=663&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=665&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=667&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=596&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=599&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=603&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=674&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=676&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?']


for url in urls:
    req = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
    for profile in soup.select('table a[href^="/game/"]'):
        profile = 'https://stats.ncaa.org'+profile.get('href')
        profiles.append(profile)

print(profiles)
```

Comment: It's completely possible the website is rate-limiting your code, so yes, "bunching", or adding `time.sleep` into the loop might help

Comment: you should use scrapy

Comment: Researching scrapy, I'm not super familiar. Added in time.sleep and seems to be the most simple solution right now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use CSS selector and select  `.smtext > a[href^="/game/"]` and it's working. As @OneCricketeer has stated, it takes load time.So I also use a bit load time.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
profiles = []
urls = ['https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=2&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=6&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=7&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=17&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=23&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=27&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=28&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=30&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=37&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=43&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=47&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=51&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=52&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=14927&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=61&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=62&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=66&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=67&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=68&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=71&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=72&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=77&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=80&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=81&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=83&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=87&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=30135&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=90&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=94&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=96&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=97&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=99&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=101&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=102&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=115&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=116&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=127&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=129&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=48&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=136&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=147&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=148&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=149&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=153&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=1013&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=285&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=786&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=156&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=158&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=165&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=167&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=169&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=172&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=173&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=178&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=176&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=30095&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=189&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=191&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=193&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=194&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=196&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=198&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=201&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=202&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=204&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=207&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=1068&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=220&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=222&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=228&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=229&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=28755&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=231&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=234&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=236&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=244&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=1092&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=248&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=249&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=251&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=255&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=253&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=254&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=260&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=261&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=1104&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=270&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=275&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=19651&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=283&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=287&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=290&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=294&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=299&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=305&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=2699&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=306&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=310&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=311&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=314&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=315&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=316&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=317&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=327&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=1157&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=331&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=340&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=342&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=346&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=352&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=355&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=28600&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=361&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=363&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=365&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=366&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=370&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=371&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=369&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=381&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=386&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=387&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=388&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=402&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=406&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=410&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=414&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=416&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=419&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=430&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=432&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=669&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=439&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=440&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=444&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=446&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=450&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=454&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=471&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=472&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=482&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=483&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=485&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=488&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=489&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=490&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=493&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=500&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=501&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=503&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=505&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=508&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=509&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=514&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=518&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=519&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=521&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=523&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=527&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=528&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=539&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=541&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=550&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=553&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=1320&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=554&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=556&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=559&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=308&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=562&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=563&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=574&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=576&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=579&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=587&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=590&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=600&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=606&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=609&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=610&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=617&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=624&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=625&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=626&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=630&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=631&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=1356&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=635&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=639&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=647&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=649&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=654&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=655&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=659&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=660&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=663&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=665&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=667&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=596&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=599&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=603&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=674&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=676&stats_player_seq=-100',
        'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?']


for url in urls:
    req = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    time.sleep(5)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
    for profile in soup.select('.smtext > a[href^="/game/"]'):
        profile = 'https://stats.ncaa.org'+profile.get('href')
        profiles.append(profile)

print(profiles)
```

**Output:**

```
['https://stats.ncaa.org/game/index/5155492?org_id=2', 'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/index/5157510?org_id=2', 'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/index/5161595?org_id=2', 'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/index/5168727?org_id=2', 'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/index/5169809?org_id=2', 'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/index/5170947?org_id=2', 'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/index/5172890?org_id=2', 'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/index/5176186?org_id=2', 'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/index/5177526?org_id=2', 'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/index/5178745?org_id=2', 'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/index/5179659?org_id=2', 'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/index/5180379?org_id=2', 'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/index/5180862?org_id=2', 'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/index/5182230?org_id=2', 'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/index/5183097?org_id=2', 'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/index/5184752?org_id=2', 'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/index/5185968?org_id=2', 'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/index/5187936?org_id=2', 'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/index/5189299?org_id=2', 'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/index/5191229?org_id=2', 'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/index/5193013?org_id=2', 'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/index/5194803?org_id=2', 'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/index/5197087?org_id=2', 'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/index/5203612?org_id=2', 'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/index/5207012?org_id=2', 'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/index/5214481?org_id=2', 'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/index/5216857?org_id=2', 'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/index/5222370?org_id=2', 'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/index/5225017?org_id=2', 'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/index/5229763?org_id=2', 'https://stats.ncaa.org/game/index/5230552?org_id=2', '
```